# Arrow with text near forest tree

Tags: arrows, forest

[image]

Hello! I am trying to insert an arrow with text parallel to the tree. Thanks!

```
    \documentclass[11pt,titlepage,oneside,openany]{book}
    \usepackage{forest}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    [A, name=a[B][C[D][E ,name=e[F][G]]]]
    \end{forest}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of just posting an image, post the code for your tree in a minimal compilable document that people can work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did almost everything yourself, even naming the nodes. I only had to add one simple Ti*k*Z command.

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[A,name=a
 [B]
 [C
  [D]
  [E ,name=e
   [F]
   [G]
  ]
 ]
]
\draw[thick,-latex] ([xshift=1cm]a.north east) -- ([xshift=1cm]e.south east)
node[midway,sloped,above]{text on arrow};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]